# asp classic: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: asp-classic, global.asa

I'm trying to do server side xml transform and am specifying the templates I want to use in the global.asa
for the paths I specify with server.MapPath. For files in the same folder, some are found and one gives an error. Any idea why?

For example, first one is found, the second one isn't
server.MapPath("/website_root/subFolder/XSL/A.xsl")

server.MapPath("/website_root/subFolder/XSL/B.xsl")

The error says msxml3.dll error '80070003'
The system cannot find the path specified

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
The problem is with the new templates added, the old declares for the files in the same folder show fine. Code below:

```vb
Dim oXSL, oXSLTemplateA, oXSLTemplateB, oXSLTemplateC, oXSLTemplateD, oXSLTemplateE
Set oXSL = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")

'A.xsl
oXSL.load server.MapPath("projectRoot/SubFolder/XSL/A.xsl")
Set oXSLTemplateA = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
oXSLTemplateA.stylesheet = oXSL
Set Application("ATemplate") = oXSLTemplateA

'B.xsl
Set oXSL = Nothing
Set oXSL = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
oXSL.load server.MapPath("/projectRoot/SubFolder/XSL/B.xsl")
Set oXSLTemplateB = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
oXSLTemplateB.stylesheet = oXSL 'ERROR ON THIS LINE
Set Application("BTemplate") = oXSLTemplateB

'C.xsl
Set oXSL = Nothing
Set oXSL = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
oXSL.load server.MapPath("/projectRoot/SubFolder2/XSL/C.xsl")
Set oXSLTemplateC = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
oXSLTemplateC.stylesheet = oXSL
Set Application("CTemplate") = oXSLTemplateC

'D.xsl
Set oXSL = Nothing
Set oXSL = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
oXSL.load server.MapPath("/projectRoot/SubFolder2/XSL/D.xsl")
Set oXSLTemplateD = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
oXSLTemplateD.stylesheet = oXSL
Set Application("DTemplate") = oXSLTemplateD

'E.xsl
Set oXSL = Nothing
Set oXSL = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument")
oXSL.load server.MapPath("/projectRoot/SubFolder2/XSL/E.xsl")
Set oXSLTemplateE = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
oXSLTemplateE.stylesheet = oXSL 'ERROR ON THIS LINE
Set Application("ETemplate") = oXSLTemplateE
```

EDIT:
If I change E.xsl to a random name which I know doesn't exist. The error is different, it'll say msxml3.dll error '80004005' The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.

Comment: Permissions perhaps?

Comment: I checked and it's the same for both files.

Comment: What is `website_root`? The path in the `Server.MapPath` should be *after* root i.e. if your website_root stays for root then you call `Server.MapPath("/subFolder/XSL/A.xsl")`. Debug your code with Response.Write and output full path after Server.MapPath is executed. The message clearly says it cannot find the path.

Comment: This code is in the global.asa Is there a way to print out a statement from there?

Comment: @user2316116 depends if it's been built as sub-sites which I've seen done. Not great but it happens.

Comment: @Megaman without more information of your webserver setup and configuration, we can only guess. Create a test.asp/aspx and output `response.write Server.MapPath("/website_root/subFolder/XSL/A.xsl")` to ensure you get the expected path that does exist.

Comment: thanks @user2316116, I tried that statement and it provided the correct physical path. I even tried with the upper and lower cases mixed and it prints the correct physical path with the right letter cases.

Comment: In the code, you don't have the starting / in `oXSL.load server.MapPath("projectRoot/SubFolder/XSL/A.xsl")` so perhaps you should remove it on the others?

Comment: no they all have that statement. In the first block, it's just set for the first time before it so I don't set it to "Nothing" before setting it to Server.CreateObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xsl file was importing another xsl file which was using the full path and wasn't finding anything. I changed that to the relative path and it worked.